# VBA - Custom Function Loops

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am new to vba and need help in creating a custom function in Excel 2010.  I will need a custom function since my ranges will change.

My data is as follows:

```
25   35  45  -5  
50  -10   0  -5  
50  -60  10  40
```

I need to create a function that will loop through each cell. If the sum of the first two cells is >= 0 then the function should grab the following cell and sum those three cells.  The loop should end when the function reaches the end of the range.  If the sum of the first two cells <0 then it should move to the next cell.  For example the sum of the first row should be 100, the second row should be 45, and the third row should be 50.

This is how far I came to my code prior to getting stuck.

```
Public Function testloop(diff As Range) As Double
Dim c As Long
For c = 1 To diff.Columns.Count
 If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, c) >= 0 Then
```

Comment: Huh? It is unclear what the specifciation is. Can you write down the rules in an algorithm? Use `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as variables for each row to represent the 4 values.

Comment: the 2nd row: 50 -10 = 40. This is >=0, so we add the last 2 cells: 40 + 0 - 5 = 35 ?? How did you get 45 ?  Third row: 50 - 60 = -10. This is <0, so we "move to the next cell" ... and do what exactly ? (from you stating total 50, I guess start from 0, so 0 + 10 + 40 = 50 ?? )

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If a + b >= 0 then sum(a,b)

Comment: Ignore my previous post.  Sorry for the confusion.The sum for row 2 should be 35.   If a + b >= 0 then move to c then if a+b+c >= 0 then move to d. The end result should be a+b+c+d.  If a+b <=0 then move to c and the summation should start at c.  For example in the third row since 50+-60=-10 then I would start my sum at 10 with the end result being 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just use a simple Excel formula .. like so:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:B1)>0,SUM(A1:B1),0)+SUM(C1:D1)
```

However, if you're dead set on VBA .. try this:

```
  Public Function strange_sum(inrange As Range) As Long
     Dim total As Long
     Dim i As Integer
     i = 0
     total = 0
     For Each cell In inrange
        i = i + 1
        total = total + cell.Value
        If i = 2 And total < 0 Then total = 0
     Next cell
     strange_sum = total
  End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Ditto!! This worked.  Unfortunately I need the VBA since my range could be anywhere from 4 to 20 variables.